Uniswap Bot with AI Contract. Is it a scam or not?
Today I found sponsorized YouTube video to make 1ETH a day with a bot in Remix.
Is it legit the code?
what you think about it?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oB_kJRjkyio
I have no experience in coding but seems done well
thank you
Adri

All Scams...Why should someone make this available for free if it works or make it generally available? Then the bots would cancel each other out over time if too many do the same thing :D

Sure, has no logic to share it. My mynd is still too prone to believe sometimes to these scams, even after years of experience I still want to believe that is true. But after being scammed some times in 2020, now I never send money if before I dont make some research to justify this illogic opportunities. After writing here I also found some YT video that explain the scam. But I already put my Q here. thank you
